# Find duplicates in particular column of file in bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I am trying to find duplicates in 9th column of file:
I tried using the following code. I am facing syntax error. Can you please help.

```
feed="09SPP"
key=${feed:0:2}
echo $key
m = `sort SPP_OUT | awk -v tk=$key '{dup[tk]++}
END { for (i_1 in dup) if (dup[i_1]>1) print i_1;}'`
echo $m
```

Comment: also let me know if the above logic to find duplicate is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
m = `sort SPP_OUT | awk -v tk=$key '{dup[tk]++}
END { for (i_1 in dup) if (dup[i_1]>1) print i_1;}'`
```

You have space around `=` and new line within the line.

Some like this:

```
m=`sort SPP_OUT | awk -v tk=$key '{dup[tk]++} END { for (i_1 in dup) if (dup[i_1]>1) print i_1;}'`
```

Or even better, no use old and deprecated back-tics, use parentheses.

```
m=$(sort SPP_OUT | awk -v tk=$key '{dup[tk]++} END { for (i_1 in dup) if (dup[i_1]>1) print i_1;}')
```

Wy use variable `i_1`?  Makes it hard to read, just use `i` and remove last `;`

```
m=$(sort SPP_OUT | awk -v tk=$key '{dup[tk]++} END { for (i in dup) if (dup[i]>1) print i}')
```

---

@Madan If you like to test if `key` has more than one hit in the text, do:

```
m=$(awk -v tk="$key" '$0~tk {a++} END {if (a>1) print a}' SPP_OUT)
```

---

To test if `n` line has duplicate:

```
awk -v tk="$key" '++a[$(tk+0)]==2 {f=1} END {if (f) print "yes"}' file
```

If `key=09` it will now test to see if column `9` has duplicate.  If so, print  `yes`
The `tk+0` is used to remove leading zero, so `09` becomes `9`

Comment: I am able to execute the command. But i am getting the column value 09. But i m not getting the duplicates value.

Comment: @Madan Edit your original post an add example data, and how you like the output to be.

Comment: @Madan You are not testing anything, so `{dup[tk]++}` this is true all the time.  And if `key` is `pattern`, you get a variable `dup[pattern]` increment for every lines.  Do you like to test if the line as `pattern` within, and then increment?

Comment: Thank you. But still facing the issue. I used your code; sorted input too. Still not able to get. `m=$(awk -v tk="$key" '$0~tk {a++} END {if (a>1) print a}' SPP_OUT | sort -n -t'|' -k9 )`

Comment: @Madan Since I do not know whats in SPP_OUT, and not sure what you like out of it, its some difficult to help.  PS output from `m` in my last post, is just one single number, how many times is `key` found in the text.  No need to sort just one number.

Comment: Can you please tell the purpose of $0~tk?

Comment: `tk="$key"` sets `tk` to `$key`=`09`.  `$0~tk` test if line contains `tk`.  So we just see if line as  `09` in it.  If yes, increment array `a` with one.  You still have not posted your files and what you like to get out of your code.

Comment: I m sorry. You got it wrong. I m not searching for 09 in my records. I need to find if 9th column has duplicates.

Comment: Thanks. I got it finally

Comment: @Madan See new update.  If its what you like, please accept it :)